# how to installing spring boot application on Mac

Tags: macos, spring-boot, init.d

Spring boot application can be easily started as Linux services using either `init.d` or `systemd`. Then we can use `stop`|`start`|`status`|`restart` commands to manage our service. Is there any similar way to manage spring boot application as service on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macOS equivalent is launchd/launchctl. There's a very detailed tutorial at http://launchd.info